# UNION query works in mysql but doesn't work the same in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I run this query in mysql it returns all the requested results correctly:

```
SELECT row_id FROM table1 WHERE status = n 
UNION ALL 
SELECT row_id FROM table2 WHERE status = n 
UNION ALL 
SELECT row_id FROM table3 WHERE status = n
```

However when I run it from PHP it returns only one record, the first row that meets the requested condition.

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT row_id FROM table1 WHERE status = n 
UNION ALL 
SELECT row_id FROM table2 WHERE status = n 
UNION ALL 
SELECT row_id FROM table3 WHERE status = n");

print_r(mysqli_fetch_array($query));
```

So `print_r` shows the following: `Array ( [0] => 1 [row_id] => 2580 )`, where 2580 is a *id* of the row from *table1* that meets the requested condition.

How to make it return the full array of results?

Comment: Do you have a loop in your php code to read all the values?

Comment: Can you try it with only "UNION" not with "UNION ALL" and also are you sure that another two tables have data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456529/mysqli-fetch-array-while-loop-columns - this might help

Comment: I had similar problem, best way is to echo the query, it identified the error for me. Basically the $query was empty because it was ill formatted because of using multiple ' ' in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to print data in loop like:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT row_id FROM table1 WHERE status = n 
UNION ALL 
SELECT row_id FROM table2 WHERE status = n 
UNION ALL 
SELECT row_id FROM table3 WHERE status = n");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Simply mysqli_fetch_array only return current row in the loop. You need to loop through it to get all the results.

Comment: I had this loop on the results all along, but I must have made a mistake and it did not work out and that is when confusion started for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. I never knew that `WHERE status = n` is valid SQL. Shouldn't it be `WHERE status = 'n'`
2. Try looping your `mysqli_fetch_array()` like this:

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        print_r($row);
    }`

Comment: It is perfectly valid SQL, as `n` *could* be a column name; but somehow I suspect it was used a placeholder.

Comment: @eggyal considering OPs first statement of `When I run this query in mysql` then it is safe to assume that `n` is a column name? I might just be inexperienced but this would only make sense if they were doing a `JOIN`

Comment: I agree that it is probably a placeholder, most likely for an integer. Quotes are only needed to denote strings, so `WHERE column=2` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, `n` *could* be a column name, even without a `JOIN` (and irrespective of whether it is run in MySQL or using some API): see, for example, [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e5ed/1/0).