# Mysql returns no error but don't give any result but in phpmyadmin it returns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a strange error.

when i run this sql:

```
select a.*, (((a.num_artigo NOT IN (select l.num_artigo from leiloes l))) | ((1 in (select n.RT from leiloes n where n.num_artigo = a.num_artigo)) << 1)) as TYPE from artigos_prazo a
```

in phpmyadmin it return a table as it was supposed to be.

but when i run it in a php script it does not return nothing, also I receive no error from the database.

```
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connet...;
    $sql = "select a.*, (((a.num_artigo NOT IN (select l.num_artigo from leiloes l))) | ((1 in (select n.RT from leiloes n where n.num_artigo = a.num_artigo)) << 1)) as TYPE from artigos_prazo a";
        echo $sql;
        echo mysqli_error($con);
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    print_r($result);
        while($row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
    print_r($row);
mysqli_close($con)
    ?>
```

It connects to the database...

Help please

Comment: The queries are different since you have EXPLAIN in $sql.

Comment: Forget the explain, was just a try :/ Sorry, the sql is the same in both scripts

Comment: You are traversing $result with the wrong syntax. Check the answer to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456529/mysqli-fetch-array-while-loop-columns

Comment: It's not the same problem...

Comment: I said to check the answer, not the question. Look at the accepted one and see the syntax to use with while and mysql_fetch_array.

Comment: Sorry I forgot is $row[], it's correct... Typing error.

Comment: But the problem was not that

Comment: what is the error you getting

Comment: I'm getting no error, that's the problem. Simple the array $result and $row are empty. But running the same SQL command on the terminal I have a result

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
while($row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
print_r($row);
```

with

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```