# Array to list/or other array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, list

I need some help with my SQL queries from php.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM datab WHERE  (`datestamp` BETWEEN '$date' AND '$date') AND (`timestamp` BETWEEN '08:00:01' AND '20:00:00')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
 //echo "$list[0]</br>";
 echo "$list[1]</br>";  //this is the column from MySQL corresponding to temperatures
 //echo "$list[2]</br>"; //this is the column from MySQL corresponding to other entries (humidity)
 //echo "$list[3]</br>";
 // echo "$list[4]</br>";
 // echo "$list[5]</br>";
 //echo "$list[6]</br>";
 // echo "$list[7]</br>";
}
```

So, I need to access my each temperature like an array or a list element and I don't know how to do it. I think the solution is to add each $list[1] element into another array inside that while.

Basicaly I want to access the element like temp[2] (or smth like that) to be the second element from the printed $list[1].

Can anyone help me?

Comment: it's already answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14456661/5857047

Answer (score 1):

Create another array for temperature:

```
$temperature = array();
while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $temperature[] = $list[1]; // so now you will be able to acess the temperature array from anywhere outside this loop
}
```

Comment: many thanks!
it works great. This is what I need it. 
sorry that I'm dumb with php but I have a project which needs to be done.