# PHP Extracting MYSQL Value Issue

Tags: php, logging, mysqli, html-table

I have 2 tables: users and transactions

In users I have: userid, name, email

And in transactions I have: id, idsender, idreceiver

I want to make a log-table showing all the transactions and I want them to be displayed like: Transaction ID - SENDER'S NAME - RECEIVER'S NAME

I tried like this but it doesn't seem to work, at "Receiver" it doesn't show anything .. :

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Transaction ID</th>";
echo "<th>Sender</th>";
echo "<th>Receiver</th>";
echo "</tr>";

    $resultuser = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users"); 
    $rowuser=mysqli_fetch_array($resultuser);

    $resulttrans = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM transactions"); 
    $rowtrans=mysqli_fetch_array($resulttrans);



    $ress=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM transactions");

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ress)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>"." same as receiver"."</td>";
            $receiver=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name FROM users WHERE userid='" . $rowtrans['idreceiver'] . "'");
            $receivername = mysqli_fetch_array($receiver);

                echo "<td>". $receivername ."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
```

Comment: See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php). `mysqli_fetch_array` returns an array or null, and you're trying to output as a simple variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array while loop columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456529/mysqli-fetch-array-while-loop-columns)

Comment: Don't use two queries, use one query that joins the two tables.

Comment: What's the purpose of the first two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use two queries. Join the two tables in one query:

```
$ress = mysqli_query("SELECT t.id, u1.name AS sendername, u2.name AS receivername
    FROM transactions AS t
    JOIN users AS u1 ON u1.userid = t.idsender
    JOIN users AS u2 ON u2.userid = t.idreceiver");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['sendername'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['receivername'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing from fetched array in `$receivername = mysqli_fetch_array($receiver);`

you should do `echo "<td>". $receivername['name'] ."</td>";`

Note:
Fetched array from `mysqli_fetch_array()` can be echoed using indexes by number `$receivername[0]` or by string `$receivername['name']`, that is where you are missing here.

Comment: Still not working,


 `$receiver=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid='" . $rowtrans['idreceiver'] . "'");


 $receivername = mysqli_fetch_array($receiver);
 

            echo "<td>". $receivername ."</td>"; `

Comment: @DizzyTudor That's the same as your question, not like the answer.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I ment `$receivername['name']`, I pasted it wrong. I have it correct now, but the field is still blank.