# Change output variables MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

If I do this kind of query:

```php
<?php
SELECT * FROMloginwhereemail = 'something@something.com';
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die("Query error");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    //(......)
}
?>
```

is there a way that the MySQL result can be with different variable names?
I mean:

```php
SELECT (first_name as foo) FROM login where email = 'something@something.com';

$first_name = $row['foo'];
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456529/mysqli-fetch-array-while-loop-columns

Comment: You should always use prepared statements when using any data in a query, no matter what the source of the data otherwise you leave yourself vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks

Comment: What you're doing should work... but on the other hand, your first snippet doesn't. Please try to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you out.