# PHP: print all the items of an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My goal: insert into a variable an array of items coming from a query and then print it

steps:

1. launch the query
2. do something with php
3. print the variable `$report = 'this is your list: $list';`

tried this:

```
    $myquery = mysqli_query($dbconnection, "SELECT ...");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($myquery)) {
      $my_array = $row['field'];
      echo "$my_array, "; /* here I've the full list*/
    }

    $report = 'this is your list:' .$my_array. '.';

    echo "$report"; /*I've only one item and not all the list*/
```

Comment: All basic questions are already answered several times.  Please enjoy the wealth of pre-existing knowledge by searching Stackoverflow before posting a new question.

Comment: Thanks. i reached my goal not using php but simply adding a "GROUP_CONCAT" in mysql query

Answer (score 0):

Your first `echo` is called several times because it is in the loop.
In every iteration you are replacing your content of `$my_array`.

Instead, try to attach it:

```
$my_array[] = $row['field'];
```

For more information see https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php

Comment: Then **echo "$report";** will raise an error.

Comment: You are right. You cannot echo an array. Try `var_dump` instead

Answer (score 0):

This is normal.
Your `while` loop doing a "step" for each row found with your query.
You assigned `$my_array` as the "column" with the name `field`.

So at the end of the `while` loop, you'll get only the last column `field` of the last row.

Instead, try this

```
$myquery = mysqli_query($dbconnection, "SELECT ...");
$myWholeList = ''; // HERE

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($myquery)) {
    $my_array = $row['field'];
    echo "$my_array, ";
    $myWholeList .= '$my_array '; // HERE
}

$report = 'this is your list:' .$my_array. '.';
echo "$myWholeList"; // HERE
```

I've done a string concatenation, but you can do it with array and `print_r()` function. Have a look on this thread to see how to append data to an array.

[mysqli_fetch_array while loop columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456529/mysqli-fetch-array-while-loop-columns)

**EDIT:**
Based on @isabella 's comment, she wants to display 7 items of array.

Two way :

- Use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` which is the best to display an array (without taking care about rendering)
- Add to `$myWholeList` variable each item.

e.g.

```
$myquery = mysqli_query($dbconnection, "SELECT ...");
$myWholeList = ''; // HERE

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($myquery)) {
    $my_array = $row['field'];
    echo "$my_array, ";

    // HERE
    foreach($row as $field) {
        $myWholeList .= $field . ' ';
    }
    $myWholeList .= '<br>'; // NEW LINE
}

$report = 'this is your list:' .$my_array. '.';
echo "$myWholeList"; // HERE
```

Comment: thanks for your reply: I tried it but when I print the $myWholeList variable it prints 7 times the string $my_array instead of printing the 7 items of the array...

Comment: @isabella  I just add some explanation about your request ;)