# PHP API only showing one user and not every user

Tags: php, mysql

Well, this is my code:

```
<?php
 
header("Content-Type:application/json");
include('connection.php');
 
 
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
     $customerData['id'] = $row['id'];
     $customerData['username'] = $row['username'];
     $customerData['password'] = $row['password'];
     $customerData['created'] = $row['created_at'];
 
     $response["users"] = $customerData;
 }
 

echo json_encode($response); exit;
 
?>
```

Currently I have two users in my database. What this code should do is to display all users in my database. At the moment the code works only so that only one user is shown. Does someone know what I have to change? Thanks in advise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_array while loop columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456529/mysqli-fetch-array-while-loop-columns)

Comment: You are over-writing `$response["users"]` on each iteration of the loop. You need to `append` new data to that array - like `$response["users"][]=$customerData;` - the answer below suggests that but does not say so

Comment: If you changed your select to just return the columns you use, you might just be able to use `mysqli_fetch_all` and not have to use a loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append to the `$response["users"]` array. You're currently overwriting it with each loop/iteration.

You can use `array_push()` to accomplish this e.g., `array_push($response['users'], $customerData);` or do it without a function call by simply appending brackets to the end of your assignment like so: `$response['users'][] = $customerData;`